# Present value of deferred annuity with varying amounts

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

An annual annuity pays the amount 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 (in dollars), the first payment occurring at the end of the second year. The present value at $=0$ of this annuity is 25 dollars at an annual effective rate $i$.

Another annual annuity pays the amount 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 (in dollars), the first payment occurring at the end of the first year. The present value at $=0$ of this annuity is $V$ dollars at an annual effective rate $i$.

What is the value of $V$?

I have been trying to do this problem for two days, but I do not know where to start. Do I need to find the annual effective rate first using the present value given? My issue with this is that since the payments are not all equal, do I need to calculate them all individually? Or is there a formula?

Thank you !!

Comment: The first annuity has only $11$ monthly instalments. Is that deliberate?

Comment: I would say that the equation in the first case is $$25=\frac{1}{q^2}+\frac{2}{q^3}+\frac{3}{q^4}+\frac{4}{q^5}+\frac{5}{q^6}+\frac{6}{q^7}+\frac{5}{q^8}+\frac{4}{q^9}+\frac{3}{q^{10}}+\frac{2}{q^{11}}+\frac{1}{q^{12}},$$ with $q=1+i$, where $i$ is the annual interest rate.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes since it starts at the end of the second year I believe it was deliberate.

Comment: @uniquesolution These are annual payments, not monthly ones, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Calculating the interest rate (numerically) is certainly one way to do it, but the problem smells like you're supposed to find some clever way of expressing the second sum in terms of the first.  So far, I haven't been able to do it.

Comment: Numerical calculation gives the value $30$, so there must be some slick way to do it.

Comment: @saulspatz I'm trying to split the annuity into two (with an increasing and a decreasing one) to then add them together and isolate the interest rate that way. This seems to be the only way I could think of to do this problem, but if you figure out something simpler, let me know!

Comment: @dery Do you agree to my expression in the comment?

Comment: @callculus The expression in your comment is correct, though in this context it is customary to call the discount rate $v$ rather than $1/q$

Comment: @saulspatz I would say that $v=\frac1{q}$. Thanks for the reply. It seems that the OP has no need to give a reply.

Comment: @callculus The solution you gave is probably good, it just doesn't look like what I have seen in class so I wasn't sure what to say.

Comment: @dery Asking is a reply as well. Just ask if something is unclear.

Comment: A little numerical experimentation lead me to believe that there is a general fact: Let $n$ be a positive integer, let $r$ be the unique positive root of $$p(x)=-n^2+\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(n+1-k)x^{n+2}$$ and let $$q(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^k+\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2}(2n+3-k)x^k$$  Then $q(r)=n^2+n$.  I hope I've typed this right.

Comment: @saulspatz This is probably correct as well but I don't think I can use this as we've only been using the regular present value formulas in class. But thank you!!

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to see the pattern in the general case than a specific one.  Hasn't worked for me in this instance, though, at least, not yet.  I may post a question on the polynomial identity if I can't figure it out.

Comment: @saulspatz Great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$p(v)=v^2+2v^3+3v^4+4v^5+5v^6+6v^7+5v^8+4v^9+3v^{10}+2v^{11}+v^{12}$$
Since $p(0)=0$, $p$ is strictly increasing on $v\geq0$, and $p(v)\to\infty$ as $v\to\infty$, there is a unique $r>0$ such that $p(r)=25$.

Now, $$\begin{align}
p(v)&=v^2(1+2v+3v^2+4v^3+5v^4+6v^5+5v^6+4v^7+3v^8+2v^9+v^{10})\\
&=v^2(1+v+v^2+v^3+v^4+v^5)^2\\
&=\left(v\frac{v^6-1}{v-1}\right)^2
\end{align}$$
where the second equation is proved in the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505429/interesting-properties-of-squares), so that $$\frac{r^7-r}{r-1}=5$$
Let $$q(v)=v+2v^2+3v^3+4v^4+5v^5+6v^6+6v^7+5v^8+4v^9+3v^{10}+2v^{11}+v^{12}$$
Then $$\begin{align}
q(v)-p(v)&=v+2v^2+3v^3+4v^4+5v^5+6v^6-(v^2+2v^3+3v^4+4v^5+5v^6)\\
&=v+v^2+v^3+v^4+v^5+v^6\\&=\frac{v^7-v}{v-1}
\end{align}$$ so that
$$q(r)-p(r)=\frac{r^7-r}{r-1}=5$$ and $$q(r)=25+5=\boxed{30}$$